# Merge pandas dataframe, with column operation

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataframe

I searched archive, but did not find what I wanted (probably because I don't really know what key words to use)

Here is my problem: I have a bunch of dataframes need to be merged; I also want to update the values of a subset of columns with the sum across the dataframes.

For example, I have two dataframes, df1 and df2:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([ [1,2],[1,3], [0,4]], columns=["a", "b"])
df2=pd.DataFrame([ [1,6],[1,4]], columns=["a", "b"])

    a   b           a   b
0   1   2       0   1   5
1   1   3       2   0   6
2   0   4
```

after merging, I'd like to have the column 'b' updated with the sum of matched records, while column 'a' should be just like df1 (or df2, don't really care) as before:

```
    a   b
0   1   7
1   1   3
2   0   10
```

Now, expand this to merging three or more data frames.

Are there straightforward, build-in tricks to do this? or I need to process one by one, line by line?

===== Edit / Clarification =====

In the real world example, each data frame may contain indexes that are not in the other data frames. In this case, the merged data frame should have all of them and update the shared entries/indexes with sum (or some other operation).

Comment: In that case you may have to merge/concat all the dfs together and then sum all the columns where there are clashes ignoring the `NaN` values

Comment: This is what I ended up experimenting. the merged data frame has multiple columns with the same names. Initially `sum` function returns error, but turns out upgrading pandas to current version fixed it.

Comment: You should post as an answer if it works for you, none of merge, join, concat will do what you want because essentially you are not merging data you are performing an operation so it's distinctively different so I can't see how this could be done in a single pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only partial, not complete solution yet. But the main point is solved:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], join = "outer", axis=1)
df4 = df3.b.sum(axis=1)
```

df3 will have two 'a' columns, and two 'b' columns. the sum() function on df3.b add two 'b' columns and ignore NaNs. Now df4 has column 'b' with sum of df1 and df2's 'b' columns, and all the indexes.

did not solve the column 'a' though. In my real case, there are quite few number of NaN in df3.a , while others in df3.a should be the same. I haven't found a straightforward way to make a column 'a' in df4 and fill value with non-NaN. Now searching for a "count" function to get occurance of elements in rows of df3.a (imagine it has a few dozens column 'a').