# merge two dataframes with some common columns where the combining of the common needs to be a custom function

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

my question is very similar to [Merge pandas dataframe, with column operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307932/merge-pandas-dataframe-with-column-operation) but it doesn't answer my needs.

Let's say I have two dataframes such as (note that the dataframe content could be float numbers instead of booleans):

```
left = pd.DataFrame({0: [True, True, False], 0.5: [False, True, True]}, index=[12.5, 14, 15.5])
right = pd.DataFrame({0.7: [True, False, False], 0.5: [True, False, True]}, index=[12.5, 14, 15.5])
```

#### right

```
        0.5    0.7
12.5   True   True
14.0  False  False
15.5   True  False
```

#### left

```
        0.0    0.5
12.5   True  False
14.0   True   True
15.5  False   True
```

As you can see they have the same indexes and one of the column is common. In real life there might be more common columns such as one more at 1.0 or other numbers not yet defined, and more unique columns on each side. 
I need to combine the two dataframes such that all unique columns are kept and the common columns are combined using a specific function e.g. a boolean OR for this example, while the indexes are always identical for both dataframes.

So the result should be:

#### result

```
        0.0   0.5    0.7
12.5   True  True   True
14.0   True  True  False
15.5  False  True  False
```

In real life there will be more than two dataframes that need to be combined, but they can be combined sequentially one after the other to an empty first dataframe.

I feel pandas.combine might do the trick but I can't figure it out from the documentation. Anybody would have a suggestion on how to do it in one or more steps.

Comment: I would do it in a few steps: deduce the common columns, apply the combination function to both, then add the non-common columns. With more than two, you'd apply these steps in-place for the very first data-frame, while looping through the other ones. Does that sound logical for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate the dataframes, and then groupby the column names to apply an operation on the similarly named columns: In this case you can get away with taking the sum and then typecasting back to bool to get the `or` operation.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([left, right], 1)
df.groupby(df.columns, 1).sum().astype(bool)
```

#### Output:

```
        0.0   0.5    0.7
12.5   True  True   True
14.0   True  True  False
15.5  False  True  False
```

---

If you need to see how to do this in a less case-specific manner, then again just group by the columns and apply something to the grouped object over `axis=1`

```
df = pd.concat([left, right], 1)
df.groupby(df.columns, 1).apply(lambda x: x.any(1))
#        0.0   0.5    0.7
#12.5   True  True   True
#14.0   True  True  False
#15.5  False  True  False
```

---

Further, you can define a custom combining function. Here's one which adds twice the left Frame to 4 times the right Frame. If there is only one column, it returns 2x the left frame.

#### Sample Data

left:

```
      0.0  0.5
12.5    1   11
14.0    2   17
15.5    3   17
```

right:

```
      0.7  0.5
12.5    4    2
14.0    4   -1
15.5    5    5
```

#### Code

```
def my_func(x):
    try:
        res = x.iloc[:, 0]*2 + x.iloc[:, 1]*4
    except IndexError:
        res = x.iloc[:, 0]*2
    return res

df = pd.concat([left, right], 1)
df.groupby(df.columns, 1).apply(lambda x: my_func(x))
```

#### Output:

```
      0.0  0.5  0.7
12.5    2   30    8
14.0    4   30    8
15.5    6   54   10
```

---

Finally, if you wanted to do this in a consecutive manner, then you should make use of `reduce`. Here I'll combine 5 `DataFrames` with the above function. (I'll just repeat the right Frame 4x for the example)

```
from functools import reduce

def my_comb(df_l, df_r, func):
    """ Concatenate df_l and df_r along axis=1. Apply the
    specified function.
    """
    df = pd.concat([df_l, df_r], 1)
    return df.groupby(df.columns, 1).apply(lambda x: func(x))

reduce(lambda dfl, dfr: my_comb(dfl, dfr, func=my_func), [left, right, right, right, right])
#      0.0  0.5  0.7
#12.5   16  296  176
#14.0   32  212  176
#15.5   48  572  220
```

Comment: Nice.... However what to do if the combining function is not a simple boolean OR and the dataframe contains numbers instead of booleans? The function could be generic but always symmetric: f(right, left)

Comment: @user10472446 See the update. You can define your own function and then combined with `reduce` you can apply that function to each consecutive join by providing a list of `DataFrames` to join.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for!