# How do you take a dataframe of daily data and merge it with a dataframe of weekly/monthly/yearly averages?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of daily data that I used to build three other dataframes of weekly, monthly, and yearly average data. I want to plot the daily data with the weekly, monthly and annual data all on the same plot, which (I assume) would mean merging all 4 data frames together as one and then plotting them that way.

I've tried merging the data together, as I already have the 3 averages dataframes and the parent daily dataframe.

To create the weekly averages dataframe, I did the following:

```
# dailydata is the parent dataframe
dailydata['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dailydata['Date'])
dailydata['weeknumber'] = dailydata['Date'].dt.week
dailydata['year'] = 'dailydata['Date'].dt.year
weeklydata = dailydata.groupby(['year', 'weeknumber']).mean()
```

To merge the daily data with the weekly data, for example, I tried:

```
merged_data = dailydata.merge(weeklydata, on = 'weeknumber', how = 'inner')
```

Which just produced an error.

How do I successfully merge the `dailydata` dataframe with the `weeklydata` dataframe in order to plot both data sets together on the same plot?

Or is there a better way to plot such data formats all together that don't require merging the dataframe together?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Can this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704840/merge-two-dataframes-with-some-common-columns-where-the-combining-of-the-common

Comment: please read: [mcve]